# Adding spaces to XMLdocument

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am trying to create html document with .NET XMLDocument classes in Winforms desktop application.

As for now I can't get to add spaces to text content.
Here is critical peace of code:

```
For Each item As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
Dim content As String = CStr(item.Value)
Dim xmlCell As XmlElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("td")
xmlCell.AppendChild(xmlDoc.CreateTextNode("&nbsp;" + content + "&#160;"))
```

I also try like this:

```
xmlCell.AppendChild(xmlDoc.CreateTextNode("     " + content + "     "))
```

... but those spaces are simply ignored in showing of html document with browser.

As is visible I have to add some spaces before and after "content", " " + content + " ".
But that don't work as expected so I have exact text (as is written literary) instead of spaces in document.

How to get spaces before and after "content" in such kind of programming?

EDIT:
Actually, non-breaking space should be OK but what happend?
Whern writing through CreateTextNode...

```
&nbsp; becomes: &amp;nbsp;
```

How to avoid that?

Comment: Try: `xmlDoc.preserveWhiteSpace = true;`. Found that here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256097%28v=vs.110%29.aspx "By default, Microsoft XML Core Services (MSXML) does not honor the xml:space attribute."

Comment: Avantol, unfortunatelly, that don't work. Probably xml and html are different in that aspect.

Comment: You should consider using HtmlDocument class then. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Hm, that is different story then and my code with XMLdocument is near to end. Maybe someone know how to get spaces in described situation.

Comment: I see you use the word browser. If you are looking at the xml through a web browser there might be a chance that it will ignore extra space as if it's an html file. Try a view source (or open in notepad) and see if the actual source does display the spaces.

Comment: Yes, there are added spaces in html code. But are ignored on browser.

Comment: I'd suggest you do the following: provide us with an example HTML of what you're trying to achieve, then of what you're actually getting as a result. Also it would really help if you were to explain WHY you are trying to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edited-in question appears to be answered fairly well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1402901/4099598): embed the NBSP character literal in the string, and the XmlDocument should take care of escaping it into entities appropriately.

Comment: Hi Nathan, I try this: Dim nbsp As XmlText = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode("\u00A0"): xmlCell.AppendChild(nbsp) ad get that text (\u00A0) before my content :)

Comment: @user973238: You're using VB for this, not C#, so the \u syntax won't do the job*. Try `xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(ChrW(&H00A0))` instead.

*No BASIC derivative I'm aware of has character escaping of any kind.

Comment: This is also possible now: xmlCell.AppendChild(xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(ChrW(&HA0) + ChrW(&HA0) + content + ChrW(&HA0) + ChrW(&HA0)))

Answer (score 1):

I see you are trying to add the non-breaking space.

Is this necessary?

Why don't you try to add just a simple space before and after?

Example:

```
" " + content + " "
```

Please also note that many XML frameworks support a property for preserving white space when reading the XML data.

Here is the property: PreserveWhiteSpace

Check this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387014%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I am trying to create html document with XML classes as is described here: http://cdmckay.org/blog/2009/02/01/creating-an-html-document-with-net/. All of suggested simply don't work in my case when I see created document through browser. But spaces ARE added if I look that html code through text editor.